# How to create a Java ArrayList in C

Tags: java, c, list, pointers, arraylist

This is my code

```
typedef struct _recorrido Elemento;
typedef struct _lista_E Lista;

struct _recorrido {
    int valor_nodo;
    Elemento *siguiente;
};

struct _lista_E {
    Elemento *primero;
    Elemento *ultimo;
    int num_elementos;
};


[...]
element = (Elemento *) malloc(sizeof (Elemento));
```

And I want to create an arrayList<> like this in Java

```
List[] object = new List[10];
```

But in C...
I mean an array of lists. I think that I have to create an array of pointers to each list's element, but dont know how.

Comment: use normal lists like (int list[10])  or implement a linked list for your own use if you require a generic list. you can also create a list like the one in java by simple arrays (by implementing functions to add/delete/resize the array). it just take some times...

Answer (score 0):

You can create array of your lists like this:

```
Lista **array = (Lista**)calloc(10, sizeof(*array));

for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
    array[i] = (Lista*)malloc(sizeof(**array));
}
```

or just:

```
Lista array[10];
```

but last array will be created on stack and it will not be good for large structures.

Comment: I've read in forums that each time you dinamically assigns memory then its necessary to free it up.

Comment: Yes, it is. You should pay attention for every malloc/calloc/realloc/new. To free this two-dimension array you have to use free in the loop as in creating and after it free pointer Lista*.